# MySQL Query doesn't get the correct records based on query (JOIN)

Tags: mysql

I have two simple tables, with the following build form:

TABLE 1

```
id - name
```

TABLE 2

```
id - name - post_id (table1.id Fkey)
```

What I want is, to get the data from the `TABLE 1` where the `TABLE 1`'s `id` matches `TABLE 2`'s `post_id`

It's pretty easy, but I have 37 records and I'm getting only 13 records.

Query:

```
SELECT posts.id FROM posts INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.id = favorites.post_id
```

When the above query is executed, the result is:

Some records that are shared by the relation (id = post_id), and the rest records are random with `post_id` value as `NULL`

Comment: 37 records in which table, posts?   Only getting 13 records might be correct, for not all posts may be in the favorites where the two id's match.  Does this make sense? You'll have to check the id data between the two and see what exists ... unless you're looking for a `LEFT JOIN` instead, perhaps?

Comment: `select T1.* from Table1 T1, Table2 T2 where T1.id = T2.post_id` - try this. I think it returns what you want.

Comment: Table 1, the `posts` table

Comment: I have checked, at least 24-25 records are shared by the same id in both tables, thats why i've put this question here.

Comment: The quesiton's problem is, records are NOT getting displayed as they should be! i know how to join but i don't know where did i mess up here in this query, as it's pretty simple JOIN query.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try it and show result

```
SELECT posts.id FROM posts LEFT JOIN favorites ON posts.id = favorites.post_id
```